# Most efficient way to sum a list in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x

Among the ways to obtain the sum of a list `A` of ints in Python are the following two:

1. Built-in `sum` function: `sum(A)`
2. Reduce function with adder lambda: `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, A)`

Is there any speed advantage to using either of these, or are their performances roughly the same?

Comment: possible duplicates [question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850877/faster-way-to-sum-a-list-of-numbers-than-with-a-for-loop) and [question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436503/summing-with-a-for-loop-faster-than-with-reduce)

Comment: Specifically, this answer addresses your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/23982749/1062679

Answer (score 5):

> Among the ways to obtain the sum of a list A of ints in Python are the
>   following two:
>
> Built-in sum function: sum(A)
>
> Reduce function with adder lambda: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, A)
>
> Is there any speed advantage to using either of these, or are their
>   performances roughly the same?

On my machine the "sum" function appears to be way faster than the "reduce" version (at least for summing 5000 arrays of size 1000).

See:

```
$ cat doit.py   
from timeit import timeit
print timeit('reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, range(1000))',number=5000)
print timeit('sum(range(1000))',number=5000)

$ python2 doit.py
0.460000038147
0.0599999427795
```

---

Update:
To address the comment, I've updated my answer to also include a 'setup' for creating the array to be summed:

```
$ cat doit2.py
from timeit import timeit

print timeit('reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, a)',setup='a=range(1000)',number=5000)
print timeit('sum(a)',setup='a=range(1000)',number=5000)

$ python2 doit2.py
0.530030012131
0.0320019721985
```

Again, the "sum" version appears to be the clear winner.

Comment: 1). For more accurate timings you should create the range in the `setup` of the `timeit` call. 2). `timeit('reduce(add, r)', setup='from operator import add;r=range(1000)', number=5000)` is around 3 times faster than using the `lambda` on my machine, but of course that's still considerably slower than just using `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer almost certainly varies depending on the implementation you're using. However, as a best practice, you should assume that the built-in function has the best performance unless you have (a) proved otherwise and (b) shown that the difference is impacting performance in your specific application.

There are two complementary reasons for this. First, it's safe to assume that the people who implement the language are concerned with performance, and that they hear every complaint (justified or not) about performance. Therefore, if there's a better implementation, it's safe to assume that they will change to that implementation as soon as possible. 
And if an even better one comes on line, you can assume that they'll change to that. This means that you get speed improvements for free, as they're discovered. 
Second, it's safe to assume that the built-in function is going to communicate better in your codebase than an inline lambda. It's just simpler to read "sum" and understand "sum" than to parse the lambda. Since programmer time is in general vastly more expensive than CPU time, it makes sense to always optimize for the former over the latter, unless there is a clear and specific reason to do otherwise.